# compare 2 arrays for intersect diff and commmon values

Tags: perl, perl-data-structures

I want to compare 2 arrays and want diff , common and intersect values  but below code is not working. 
No error message all I can see Array as an value although I am calling $difference[0] so I doubt if the code is correct.

```
   sub updatedevice() {
my $n = {};

my $Device_LINK = $server->object("ICF_PersistentDataSet",$devicelinks);
my $Temp_Device_LINK = $server->object("ICF_PersistentDataSet",$tempdevicelinks);

my @current_devicelist = @{ $Device_LINK->invoke("get") };
my @temp_devicelist = @{ $Temp_Device_LINK->invoke("get") };

my %temp_list;
my %current_list;

my $size = @current_devicelist;
for ($n=0; $n < $size; $n++) {
       our $device=$current_devicelist[$n][0];
        DEBUG( "DEBUG: - devicelinks  values $device  " );   --- > able to print this value of device "ABC-DCFE41->90"

my $size = @temp_devicelist;
for ($n=0; $n < $size; $n++) {
      our $tempdevicelinks=$temp_devicelist[$n][0];
DEBUG( "DEBUG: - temp plc links values $tempdevicelinks " ); --- > able to print this value of device "GHJKL-poiu->78"

my %count = ();
foreach my $device (@current_devicelist, @temp_devicelist) {
    $count{$device}++;
}
my @difference = grep { $count{$_} == 1 } keys %count;
my @intersect  = grep { $count{$_} == 2 } keys %count;
my @union      = keys %count;

DEBUG( "DEBUG: - difference links values $difference[0] " );
DEBUG( "DEBUG: - intersect links values $intersect[0] " );
DEBUG( "DEBUG: - union links values $union[0] " );

                }
        }
}
```

Comment: Do the `...->invoke` methods return an array or a reference to an array? From what you've said I'm guessing a reference to an array.

Comment: Thanks for response Mob !!! yes I am getting array from dataset my @current_devicelist = $Device->invoke("get"); and getting the device value as "my $device=@current_devicelist[0]; "..

Comment: @user3457622 at the top of the code, put `use strict;` and `use warnings;`. then run it. Also, you should try using [Data::Dumper](http://search.cpan.org/~smueller/Data-Dumper-2.151/Dumper.pm) and provide the output of `Dumper(@current_devicelist)`

Comment: Gabs I am not getting any output from Dumper option .. I wrote like use Data::Dumper 'Dumper';  and print Dumper(@current_devicelist); I can see as below : DEBUG: - union links values ARRAY(0x2a693a0)
DEBUG: - Difflinks  values ARRAY(0x2a693a0)
DEBUG: - Intersec  values

Comment: Please print result of this: `print ref($current_devicelist[0])`

Comment: Hi DVK ,There is no output if I use above statement .. But I can see output. our $device=$current_devicelist[$n][0];
DEBUG( "DEBUG: - devicelinks  values $device;

Comment: Thank you sooooo much DVK you are genious .... Issue resolved ... Thank you so much for you timee ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're assigning array reference (returned from `invoke` to an array).

Your statement of "see 'array' as a value" is a dead giveaway that you're manipulating array references (instead of arrays) - when printed, they turn into strings like this: `'ARRAY(0x349014)'`

The problem is that you're taking an array reference (a scalar), and assigning it to an array - which imposes list context on your value, and turns that scalar into a list with its only element being that scalar. **Thus you simply store the array reference as the first and only element of the array** - instead of storing the list of values that's being referenced like you intended.

---

To demonstrate:

```
my @current_devicelist = (1,3); # Assign real arrays
my @temp_devicelist = (2,3);

my %count = ();
foreach my $device (@current_devicelist, @temp_devicelist) {
    $count{$device}++;
}

my @difference = grep { $count{$_} == 1 } keys %count;
my @intersect  = grep { $count{$_} == 2 } keys %count;
my @union      = keys %count;

use Data::Dumper;
print Data::Dumper->Dump([\@difference, \@intersect, \@union]
                        ,["difference","intersect","union"]);
```

This prints:

```
$difference = [
                '1',
                '2'
              ];
$intersect = [
               '3'
             ];
$union = [
           '1',
           '3',
           '2'
         ];
```

---

Now, if you mimique what your code was doing instead by changing the first 2 lines to:

```
my @current_devicelist = [1,3]; # Assign reference
#    Works the same as if you said 
# my @current_devicelist = ([1,3]);
#    or
# my $current_devicelist[0] = [1,3];

my @temp_devicelist = [2,3];
```

... you get:

```
$difference = [
                'ARRAY(0x349014)',
                'ARRAY(0x349114)'
              ];
$intersect = [];
$union = [
           'ARRAY(0x349014)',
           'ARRAY(0x349114)'
         ];
```

---

**To fix your problem, you can do one of 4 things**:

1. Simply dereference your returned array references, using `@{}` dereference:

   ```
   my @current_devicelist = @{ $Device->invoke("get")      };
   my @temp_devicelist    = @{ $Temp_Device->invoke("get") };
   ```
2. Change `invoke()` method - if you can - to return an array instead of array reference:

   ```
   # Old code: 
   # return $myArrRef;
   # New Code:
   return @$myArrRef;
   ```
3. Change `invoke()` method - if you can - to return an array OR an arrayref based on context (using [`wantarray`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/wantarray.html)):

   ```
   # Old code: 
   # return $myArrRef;
   # New Code:
   return wantarray : @$myArrRef : $myArrRef;
   ```
4. Change your code to use array references

   ```
   my $current_devicelist = $Device->invoke("get");
   my $temp_devicelist = $Temp_Device->invoke("get");

   my %count = ();
   foreach my $device (@$current_devicelist, @$temp_devicelist) {
       $count{$device}++;
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks DVK for detailed explaination. I adopted the 1st solution but still values are showing in arrays : my device list is alpha numeric :  difference links values ARRAY(0x34276a0)
intersect links values
union links values ARRAY(0x34276a0)

Comment: System not allowing me to post the original code due to size issue. can I send you an email ..?

Comment: Actaully my requirement is to remove the addtional device after getting the difference.

Comment: Please let me know if you looking into my original post. I would be really grateful.